# Modifying a timeline from codepen.io

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I found a design a vertical timeline from codepen that I want to use in my website https://codepen.io/web_designer_sanchit/pen/eLjvyw.

I want to modify it to my own choice of design since I'm too lazy too create one from scratch. What can do I do to modify it so that I can have the `div.time` on the **left** and the  `div.content` on the **right**?

I want this to apply for **all of my content**. Here is the code.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600');
}

h1{
  font-size:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.timeline{
  position:relative;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:40px 0;
  width:1000px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.timeline:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:#c5c5c5;
}
.timeline ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.timeline ul li{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  padding:20px 40px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd){
  float:left;
  text-align:right;
  clear:both;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even){
  float:right;
  text-align:left;
  clear:both;
}
.content{
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):before
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  top:24px;
  right:-6px;
  background:rgba(233,33,99,1);
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px rgba(233,33,99,0.2);
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even):before
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  top:24px;
  left:-4px;
  background:rgba(233,33,99,1);
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px rgba(233,33,99,0.2);
}
.timeline ul li h3{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  color:rgba(233,33,99,1);
  font-weight:600;
}
.timeline ul li p{
  margin:10px 0 0;
  padding:0;
}
.timeline ul li .time h4{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:14px;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) .time
{
  position:absolute;
  top:12px;
  right:-165px;
  margin:0;
  padding:8px 16px;
  background:rgba(233,33,99,1);
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:18px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px rgba(233,33,99,0.3);
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) .time
{
  position:absolute;
  top:12px;
  left:-165px;
  margin:0;
  padding:8px 16px;
  background:rgba(233,33,99,1);
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:18px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px rgba(233,33,99,0.3);
}
@media(max-width:1000px)
{
  .timeline{
    width:100%;
  }
}
@media(max-width:767px){
  .timeline{
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:0;
  }
  h1{
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .timeline:before{
    left:20px;
    height:100%;
  }
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd),
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even)
  {
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
  }
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):before,
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even):before
  {
    top:-18px;
    left:16px;
  }
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) .time,
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even) .time{
    top:-30px;
    left:50px;
    right:inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timeline</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
  <h1><center>Timeline</center></h1>
  <div class="timeline">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          <h4>January 2018</h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          <h4>February 2018</h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          <h4>March 2018</h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change CSS for this. Replace this CSS with your's

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600");
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 40px 0;
  width: 1000px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.timeline:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #c5c5c5;
}
.timeline ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.timeline ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline ul li {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
}
.content {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.timeline ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 24px;
  left: -4px;
  background: rgba(233, 33, 99, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(233, 33, 99, 0.2);
}
.timeline ul li h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: rgba(233, 33, 99, 1);
  font-weight: 600;
}
.timeline ul li p {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.timeline ul li .time h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.timeline ul li .time {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: -165px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background: rgba(233, 33, 99, 1);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(233, 33, 99, 0.3);
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .timeline {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .timeline {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .timeline:before {
    left: 20px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd),
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even) {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):before,
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even):before {
    top: -18px;
    left: 16px;
  }
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) .time,
  .timeline ul li:nth-child(even) .time {
    top: -30px;
    left: 50px;
    right: inherit;
  }
}
```

Or you can check here: https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/vYELXOd

Comment: Hey thanks man. That looks much better than what I was trying to modify it last night. Mine looks ugly and yours looks better.